# How to write a recursive function in python

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, recursion

I have been stuck on the solution to this question for quite a while i have written a piece of code that works as requested but i seems to get an error at the end of the compilation

> You need to design an iterative and a recursive function called
>   replicate_iter and replicate_recur respectively which will receive two
>   arguments: times which is the number of times to repeat and data which
>   is the number or string to be repeated.
>
> The function should return an array containing repetitions of the data
>   argument. For instance, replicate_recur(3, 5) or replicate_iter(3,5)
>   should return [5,5,5]. If the times argument is negative or zero,
>   return an empty array. If the argument is invalid, raise a ValueError.

my code is as below:

```
def replicate_iter(times,data):

    emptyArray = []
    if not isinstance(data, int) and not isinstance(data, str):
        raise ValueError
    if times <= 0:
        print emptyArray
    if not isinstance(times,int):
        raise ValueError
    else:
        while times > 0:
            emptyArray.append(data)
            times -= 1
        return emptyArray

array = []

def replicate_recur(times,data):

    if not isinstance(data,int) and not isinstance(data,str):
        raise ValueError
    if not isinstance(times,int):
        raise ValueError
    if times <= 0 and len(array) != 0:
        return array
    elif times <= 0 and len(array) <=0:
        return []
    else:
        array.append(data)
        replicate_recur(times - 1,data)
```

Kindly assist with suggestions please

error message :
[image]

Comment: Put your error traceback as code not image.

Comment: Thank you. Would do. New to this

Comment: No sweat. Simply [edit] your question to contain the error message as text instead of as an image, so that it can be found by the search.

Answer (score 1):

First, think about this:

```py
def f(times,data):
  return [] if times == 0 else f(times - 1,data) + [data]

print(f(3,5)) # [5,5,5]
```

Now, with regard to your recursive solution, (1) in order to access `array`, `replicate_recur` would need a declaration at its outset, "`global array`," since the variable, `array`, is declared outside of the function's scope; and (2) modify the recursive call, "`replicate_recur(times - 1,data)`," to "`return replicate_recur(times - 1,data)`," in order for the function to actually return a value when `times` is greater than zero. (That said, as I understand, it's generally considered undesirable form to have global accumulators for recursive functions.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This worked for me.

Could you kindly explain how the line works:
return replicate_recur(times - 1,data) +[data]

def replicate_recur(times,data):
    if not isinstance(data, int) and not isinstance(data, str):
        raise ValueError
    if not isinstance(times, int):
        raise ValueError
    if times <= 0:
        return []
    else:
        return replicate_recur(times - 1,data) +[data]

Comment: @MrTerfa with regards to the one-liner, think what `f(times - 1,data)` would return if `times` were `1`. Now think what would that return value `+ [data]` become? Then think, what if we had three calls like that in succession?

Comment: @MrTerfa With regards to modifying your original recursion, when you first call the function with `times` greater than 0, the function is not expected to return anything. It does make another call to the same function which modifies the external `array` but simply returns nothing. When finally we get to the `return array` line, that return is not issued to the original call since there was no request for it. Prefixing the recursive call with `return` means we're expecting to return the value from the recursive call, which, when we get to `return array`, propagates through the previous calls.

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want based on the example you gave:

```
array = []
def replicate_recur(times, val):
    if(isinstance(times, int) and times > 0):
        array.append(val)
        return replicate_recur(times-1, val)
    return array
print(replicate_recur(3, 5)) # [5,5,5]



array = []
def replicate_iter(times, val):
    if(isinstance(times, int) and times > 0):
        for i in range(times):
            array.append(val)
        return array
    raise ValueError
print(replicate_iter(3, 5)) #[5,5,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not use a global variable. A second call to your function leads to wrong results. Use a internal function or optional parameter instead.

```
def replicate_recur(times,data, array=None):
    if array is None:
        array = []
    if times <= 0:
        return array
    array.append(data)
    return replicate_recur(times - 1, data, array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should split up the logic, always becomes more readable, so it becomes easier to implement. You should avoid global variables, especially global lists, they will cause you much pain.

```
def rep_rec(times, data, pack=[]):
    pack += [data]
    return pack if times < 2 else rep_rec(times-1, data, pack)


def replicate_recur(times, data):
    if not times or not data:
        return []
    if isinstance(times, int) and (isinstance(data, int) or isinstance(data, str)):
        return rep_rec(times, data) if times > 0 else []
    raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
A.  In recursions, in general, some input is minimized until some minimum condition.
    "eg: in f(x-2), x is the input" 



B.  In the following recursion, multiples of x "eg: x TIMES f(x-2)" are
    computed as x gets smaller and smaller by 2 "eg: f(x MINUS 2)", 
    until x finally reaches 1 "eg: if x==ONE return 1", the minimum CONDITION value.



C.  The recursion multiplies by many values generated by calls of function "f",
    until mininum is reached.
    "eg: x TIMES value-AT-f-CALL_a(x-2) TIMES value-AT-f-CALL_b(x-2)....



D.  When mininum CONDITION is reached, or in other words, when x reaches 1, the recursion 
    multiplies by 1, instead of another value generated by function "f" call.
    "eg: x TIMES value-AT-f-CALL_a(x-2) TIMES value-AT-f-CALL_b(x-2) TIMES 1"

    NOTE: This is why the recursion ends, as it no longer multiplies by value at f-call.



E.  In "TIMES 1" in D above, because 1 is the minimum RETURN value
    "eg: if x==1: return ONE", this means the minimum CONDITION is reached.

    NOTE: if we had x PLUS f(x-2), then the mininum value would be 
    ADDED TO (instead of multiplied by) the SUM (instead of the product).
"""

def f(x):
    """This is a recursive function f to generate product of x, as x decreases by 2"""
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (x * f(x-2))
```